# link page to another with id

Tags: html, css, tabbing

i have this code here:

```
 <ul>
                <li class="underUl"><a class="ulA" name="History" href="about.php#History"> - History</a></li>
                <li class="underUl"><a class="ulA" name="Concept" href="about.php#Concept"> - The Concept</a></li>
                <li class="underUl"><a class="ulA" name="Choose_CST" href="about.php#Choose_CST">- Why Choose CST?</a></li>
                <li class="underUl"><a class="ulA" name="Management" href="about.php#Management">- Management</a></li>
                <li class="underUl"><a class="ulA" name="Departments" href="about.php#Departments">- Department</a></li>

            </ul>
```

and in the other page i have these divs:

```
<div id="History">history</div>
<div id="Concept">concept</div>
<div id="Choose_CST">CST</div>
 <div id="Management">management</div>
  <div id="Departments">Departments</div>
```

so i want to open on the div that the user choose refering to the id in `<ul>` tag? any idea? for example if a user click on management i want to automatically open the other page on management div etc... thanks in advance

Comment: That should work. What happens when you try to navigate to, say div `#Management` when clicking on the link with the url `about.php#Management`?

Comment: It is possible you have some script issues

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written should work but you can try to use

```
<div id="History" name="History">history</div>
<div id="Concept" name="Concept">concept</div>
<div id="Choose_CST" name="Choose_CST">CST</div>
<div id="Management" name="Management">management</div>
<div id="Departments" name="Departments">Departments</div>
```